Matplotlib: width of colorbar below a column of matshow
I have a column of matshow images and below the bottom one I want to place a colorbar with a width that is the same as that of the image(s).
I tried following the suggestion of Set Matplotlib colorbar size to match graph but implementing this shrinks the bottom plot:
MWE:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, dpi=200)

for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    
divider = make_axes_locatable(axes[1])
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0.25)    

fig.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal', cax=cax)

plt.show()



If you pass the original array of axes to colorbar then the colorbar axes is automatically created by stealing space from both of them.  Using compressed layout ensures that the colorbar is the right size relative to the original axes.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, layout='compressed')

for ax in axes.flat:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)    

fig.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal', ax=axes)

plt.show()



This gives ValueError: 'compressed' is not a valid value for layout; supported values are 'constrained', 'tight' ...

@EduardTetzlaff compressed layout was introduced at v3.6 https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#compressed-layout-for-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes

ahhh the apt repos was not updating matplotlib...thanks :-)

Using divider steals room from the ax, in height here.
And since using matshow, the aspect ratio of the ax should be 1, so it also shrinks it on width.
One solution is to create the cax for the colorbar independently, and then force it to have the width of the ax:
Note: Using tight_layout() afterwards or resizing the figure will mess this up.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

fig, (*axes, cax) = plt.subplots(3, 1, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": [1, 1, 0.05]})

for ax in axes:
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10, 10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(im, orientation="horizontal", cax=cax)

(xmin, _), (xmax, _) = axes[0].get_position().get_points()
(_, ymin), (_, ymax) = cax.get_position().get_points()
cax.set_position(Bbox([[xmin, ymin], [xmax, ymax]]))

plt.show()



Weirdly, it is also messed up when using plt.subplots_adjust() even if it is set after the colorbar is invoked - what is the correct way dealing with hspaces for example?
